# what's the correct way to crop art when saving for web in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to save a bunch of illustrations for web use, and I cannot find any 'crop to art dimensions' option when saving them. I've therefore been creating a new artboard for each illustration by clicking on the art with the artboard tool, then deleting the old artboard.

This works OK except the new artboard ignores the stroke, so I then have to go back and tweak all the edges of the artboard before saving, or else the stroke edges get cut off. This gets old after hundreds of illustrations. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Which version of Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

the solution turned out to be the 'clip to artboard' option in the image-size tab under save for web. this option works great provided the artboard is smaller than the art and you turn it on (in which case all the art is saved), or the artboard is larger than the art and you turn it off (in which case the saved file shrinks to fit the art, ignoring the size of the artboard). my problem was having this option on while the artboard was larger than my art

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it in Adobe Illustrator, but there are 3rd party programs that will do it in batches.

I have a rather inelegant one I wrote for my wife, but I posted the complete code at [pypicresizer](http://code.google.com/p/pypicresizer/) on Google code.  I suspect there are a number of others that are a bit more user friendly than the one I wrote out there.